# Chaining populate in mongoose causes error

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a problem with chaining populate in **Mongoose**.

I have a pet schema and I have declared a method like this:

```js
petSchema.methods.populateForLang = async function(lang) {
...
}
```

Inside this method, I am trying to populate some docs, and this populate works fine:

```js
return await this.populate({path:'type', select: 'title en'});
```

I also have this populate that works fine:

```js
return await this.populate({path: 'petGender', select: 'title en'});
```

But when I chain them together:

```js
await this.populate({path: 'petGender', select: 'title en'}).populate({path:'type', select: 'title en'});
```

I get the error:

```js
this.populate(...).populate is not a function
```

What is going on?

Comment: Can you post the code where `this.populate` is called? You need to call `populate` on the Model. You have called `populate` on `this` but without further code it's difficult to predict what `this` is. Each `populate` returns a promise so it looks like your second `populate` is being called on the promise and not an instance the Model class.

Comment: You can populate them in one populate as an array model  ==> ```await this.populate([{ path: 'petGender', select: 'title en' }, { path:'type', select: 'title en' }]);```

Comment: @JQueeny see my edit

Comment: @OnurDoğan this worked! Thanks. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Christoforos Perfect! I posted the answer. Thank you too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to populate **more than one schema**, then you can populate them **in one as an array model**:

```js
await this.populate([
    { path: 'petGender', select: 'title en' }, 
    { path:'type', select: 'title en' }
]);
```